# filter method in try block is not working in django

Tags: python, django, filter, try-catch

I have a model called properties which contains product details with the respective user IDs.
The user id is called uid in the model.

I wrote a function in views.py to get the products that are only posted by logged-in user.
I use the **filter** method in it, but it's not working.
How can I solve this?

````
def view_products(request):
    try:
        user = request.user.id
        c = properties.objects.filter(uid=user,status=True)       
        return render(request,'view_products.html',{'c':c})
        
    except:
        txt = """<script>alert('You have no properties to view...');window.location='/userhome/';</script>"""
        return HttpResponse(txt)```
````

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: even though there is nothing to return with the filter method, the HTML page is rendering.

I want to render the page  only if there is anything returning from properties model.

Comment: is uid a ForeignKey to user model?

Comment: no.
but it contains corresponding user ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I know, `AnonymousUser` does have `id` field, which can be even `None`, and if you use `.filter()` it does not raise exception. How do you want to handle except logic?

You should write it this way:

```py
def view_products(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = request.user.id
        c = properties.objects.filter(uid=user, status=True)
        return render(request, 'view_products.html', {'c': c})
    txt = """<script>alert('You have no properties to view...');window.location='/userhome/';</script>"""
    return HttpResponse(txt)
```

`is_authenticated` is flag/property where you can easily handle if user is authenticated (logged in) or not.